# LibreOffice Calc: how to pad number to fixed decimals when used within formula?

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, cell-format

In a LibreOffice spreadsheet, I want to display numbers (actually, prices) with two decimals. When a cell contains just a number, I can format it to do automatic padding.

But sometimes I have cases where I concatenate strings, like this:

[image]

Image says it all, I guess. Is there a **function or expression** to pad a string or number, rather than doing this through a cell's formatting properties?

Comment: Excel has a `TEXT` function which does exactly what you need. I don't know libreoffice, but suppose it has something similar too.

Comment: @MátéJuhász thanks, I got it working with `FIXED` but I noticed `TEXT` is even more versatile.

Answer (score 5):

Solved!
I couldn't find this it at first, but I've got it: `FIXED(C1,2)`